# angular forEach not working with in ng-if function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

angular forEach not working with ng-if function but working using simple if Please check fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/hzdyhx4n/

```
angular.module('app5', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
$scope.z = [ { name: 'aa', id: 55, picture: [1,4,3] } ];
$scope.display = function(x) {
    angular.forEach(x.picture, function(val,key){
        console.log(val);
        if (val === 4) {
            console.log("true");
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log("false");
            return false;
       }
    });
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `ngIf`, it's your method that doesn't return `true` (it returns `undefined` which is falsy value). You need to understand that returning from [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't propagate outside as function return. In your case, you can use convenient [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method:

```
$scope.display = function(x) {
    return x.picture.some(function(val, key) {
        return val === 4;
    });
};
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/hzdyhx4n/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this scheme:

```
    angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.z = [1,2,3];
        $scope.display = function(x) {
         return x(function(val, key) {
            return val === 1;
         });
        };
    });

    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller='ctrl'>
       <div ng-repeat=" x in z"> 
           <div ng-if="display(x)" >  
               display this
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i can't use this actually i made a simple example but in my application i need to first use foreach to check an id then use return

Answer (score 0):

your `$scope.display` method returns `undefined`, and `ng-if` evaluates `undefined` to false, hence nothing is displayd

Answer (score 0):

bro try this code..
it's works

```
    <div ng-app="app5" >
<div ng-controller='ctrl'> 
    <div ng-repeat=" x in z" >  
        <png-if="display(x)" >display this<p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and

```
angular.module('app5', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.z = [ { name: 'aa', id: 20, picture: [,1,2,4,3] } ];
      $scope.display = function(x) {
        angular.forEach(x.picture, function(val,key){
            console.log(val);
            if (val === 4) {
                alert("ho");
                console.log("true");
                return true;
            } else {
                console.log("false");
                return false;
           }
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: <p ng-if="display(x)"> display this </p>

Comment: actually it returns false,true and it continuous based upon values..we need to break if return true..